# How to split a string with multiple delimiters and join parts in vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good day All,

I would like some input on the following.

I have a function that split parts of a string and converts single digits to double digits.
The function uses '.' as a delimiter then joins the parts again by a different delimiter.

When I call the function I simply add "=Outliner(C3)" to the cell I want the formatting to happen.

Everything works beautiful. If I put 14.1.1.1 the function returns 14-01-01-01 which is exactly what I need it to do.

Now a new scenario have come up where I am getting the number as 14.1.1-1 and now the function returns 14-01-01-**43831** which is not what I want. I still want to have 14-01-01-01.

Is there an easy fix to the function. I have added the code below.

```
Function Outliner(S As String) As String
  Dim x As Long, Parts() As String
  Parts = Split(S, ".")
  For x = 0 To UBound(Parts)
    Parts(x) = Format(Parts(x), "00")
  Next
  Outliner = Join(Parts, "-")
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
Parts = Split(S, ".")
```

with

```
Parts = Split(Replace(S, "-", "."), ".")
```

Comment: seems that you are missing the quotes around the dot. otherwise i think it should do it.

Comment: Where? @SNicolaou ;)

Comment: you have edited it as i wrote my comment. all good now.